# Call to a member function extend() issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, wamp

I tried to import my Magento project into my local machine (wamp server), But I was not able to access it, i got the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\*******\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 619`[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think magento can't read `xml` files. So check all `xml` file permissions or run `magecleanup`

Also,
please check `local.xml`. There may be a typo when changing password or something

Comment: I try this but no use. the issue remain same.

Comment: please check `local.xml`. There may be a typo when changing password or something

Comment: Yes, the message occurs when a required node in the XML is missing. I would suspect an incomplete local.xml as well.

Comment: @bamakannaiyan: does this helps ?